# How to resolve the Method binding issue with that of delegate type?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create my own  ContextMenuOpening event (Event ContextMenuOpening name should be same as FrameworkElement class) when I tried to trigger that event from Xaml page its throwing “Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type” but its works fine when I hook the event in code behind.

Please find the below code Snippet to reproduce issue and provide suggestion on this.

XAML

```
 <local:ContextMenuEvetTest  x:Name="menu"  ContextMenuOpening="menu_ContextMenuOpening" />
```

Code Behind

```
 #region Main Class
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.menu.ContextMenuOpening += menu_ContextMenuOpening;
    }

    void menu_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs e)
    {
    }
} 
#endregion

#region Base Class

public class ContextMenuEvet : Control
{
    public ContextMenuEvet()
    {

    }
    public delegate void ContextMenuOpeningEventHandler(object sender, ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs e);

    public new event ContextMenuOpeningEventHandler ContextMenuOpening;

    internal void GetContextMenuOpeningEvent(ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContextMenuOpening != null)
            ContextMenuOpening(this, e);
    }

} 
#endregion

#region Derived Class

public class ContextMenuEvetTest : ContextMenuEvet
{
    static ContextMenuEvetTest()
    {

    }
} 
#endregion

#region EventsArgument

public class ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{

}
#endregion
```

Thanks in advance.

Jeyasri M

Comment: try to make everything public.

Comment: Hi AnjumSKhan,thanks for fast reply.i tried that also but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your event definition to :

```
public new event ContextMenuEventHandler ContextMenuOpening
        {
            add
            {
                base.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.ContextMenuOpeningEvent, value);
            }
            remove
            {
                base.RemoveHandler(FrameworkElement.ContextMenuOpeningEvent, value);
            }
        }
```

and remove this,

```
if (ContextMenuOpening != null)
            ContextMenuOpening(this, e);
```

and use,

```
internal void GetContextMenuOpeningEvent(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContextMenuOpening(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But my aim is  to use “Custom EventArgs(ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs)  which inherits from CancelEventArgs Class” is not  “RoutedEventArgs”.

For that scenario event gets trigger while accessed from CS.
menu.ContextMenuOpening += menu_ContextMenuOpening; 

For the same scenario when hook the same event in Xaml page getting binding error.
<local:ContextMenuEvet  x:Name="menu"  ContextMenuOpening="menu_ContextMenuOpening" />

Comment: In Other Word:
If I rename ContextMenuOpening event name as something else I am not getting any error. My assumption is event try to access ContextMenuEventHandler Delegate of  FrameworkElement Class.

Warning if I create event without new key word:
'Contextmenu_UI.ContextMenuEvet.ContextMenuOpening' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ContextMenuOpening'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. 
 
It’s so strange to find solution , Please share your ideas if any.

Comment: @JeyaSri delete your answer, it is useless.